# Inserting into database with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, database, backend

How does one use a NodeJS back-end to execute a function then store that value into a database?

Comment: https://kedarsedai.github.io/blog/2020/03/11/Build-RestAPIs/ you can have a look

Answer (score 0):

A popular approach is to combine [Node.JS](https://nodejs.org) (as a REST API back-end server) with [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com) (a NoSQL database system). The Node.JS application exposes a series of endpoints for the outer world to interact with (e.g. create user, delete user, update user's preferences, etc.) and, under the hood, each endpoint has its own business logic, related to its scope.

Check out this [guide](https://zellwk.com/blog/crud-express-mongodb/) for more.

Answer (score 0):

A common approach is to use a [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) in case of relational databases, two popular ORM in node.js ecosystem are [sequelize](https://sequelize.org/) and [TypeORM](https://typeorm.io/), in case of databases like MongoDB you can use a ODM a popular library is [mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com)

There is a lot of tutorials in the web [this](https://medium.com/@uix/building-a-rest-api-using-node-and-mongodb-bf7ac086e8f7) one of my favorites one using: Node, Express (Web Server) and MongoDB